# How to create a global state with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

Suppose I have a simple mvvm,

```
interface UserRepository {
    fun getUsers(): List<User>
}

class UserService: UserRepository {
    override fun getUsers(): List<User> {
        return listOf(User(id = 1, name = "Jane"), User(id = 2, name = "Alex"))
    }
}

class UserViewModel(
    private val userService: UserRepository
): ViewModel() {
    val users: MutableState<List<User>> = mutableStateOf(ArrayList())

    init {
        getUsers()
    }

    private fun getUsers() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            var results = userService.getUsers()
            users.value = results
        }
    }
}
```

I use this view model as follows,

```
@Composable
fun ListScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel = remember {
        UserViewModel(UserService())
    }
    ListScreenScaffold(navController, viewModel.users.value)
}

@Composable
fun ListScreenScaffold(users: List<User>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(users.size, key = {
            index -> users[index].id
        }) { index ->
            val user = users[index]
            Text(user.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Now how do I save this list of users globally so that the users are loaded only once or should I create a singleton viewmodel?

Comment: Cache it in your repository. Make that repository be a managed singleton in your preferred dependency inversion framework (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.).

Comment: I am sorry I am new to MVVM but is repository supposed to store data? Shouldn't the viewmodel be singleton here? @CommonsWare

Comment: "is repository supposed to store data?" -- it certainly can *cache* data. Usually, you store data in a persistent place (file, database, Web service, etc.). "Shouldn't the viewmodel be singleton here?" -- no. See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide for a rough overview of Google's architecture recommendations.

Comment: No I mean "store data" as in store data locally in memory. Because view model is the one that stores the data locally right. Is it possible for you to explain why view model shouldn't be the singleton? Thanks @CommonsWare

Comment: Just saw you edited answer. Thanks @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

1. If your app is for playing, use state hoisting
2. If your app is small, use live data with ViewModel and create a global class, and you should instantiate in your main activity.
3. if your app needs a lot of real-time changes, use flow.
4. Use a dagger hilt if your app is medium or enormous and needs dependency injection.
5. If your app is medium or enormous and needs real-time updates, you could mix Flow with Dagger Hilt.
6. If you need to save data locally, you could add Room.

You could mix all or not, and it depends on your needs. I recommend you investigate those libraries and the problems that they solve.

Each app has different needs. Only follow good practices with the correct architecture and design patterns, to mix all of them or use only one or create your own solution.